# is it good have multi level fields in elasticsearch document?

Tags: elasticsearch

is it good have multi level fields in elasticsearch document?

if yes what how to search documents with nested fields

I didn't see documentation regarding on elasticsearch docshttps://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index.html

Multi level I mean nested fields

````
{
 "account_number": 0,
    "balance": 16623,
    "firstname": "Bradshaw",
    "lastname": "Mckenzie",
    "age": 29,
    "gender": "F",
    "address": {
        "244 Columbus Place",
        "employer": "Euron",

        "email": {
            "personal":"bradshawmckenzie@euron.com",
            "work": "bradshawmckenzie@euron.com"
        }
        "city": "Hobucken",
        "state": "CO"
    }
}```

In about document address and email inner objects
````

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is completely fine to have multiple levels of objects.

However, your current JSON document is not valid. I assume it should be more like this.

```
{
    "account_number": 0,
    "balance": 16623,
    "firstname": "Bradshaw",
    "lastname": "Mckenzie",
    "age": 29,
    "gender": "F",
    "address": "244 Columbus Place",
    "employer": "Euron",
    "email": {
        "personal": "bradshawmckenzie@euron.com",
        "work": "bradshawmckenzie@euron.com"
    },
    "city": "Hobucken",
    "state": "CO"
}
```

To access inner objects, you can use dot notation. For example:

```
GET my-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "email.personal": "bradshawmckenzie@euron.com"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of having "multiple levels" in Elasticsearch, there are pros and cons for each approach. The following article explains them well:
https://www.elastic.co/blog/managing-relations-inside-elasticsearch